# Where can I access the ASP.NET Configuration on a production server?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-membership, production-environment

Currently, I have successfully deployed my ASP.NET App in the Production server.

Now I need to create the roles and users with the MySQL Membership Provider.

So far I have done this in localhost using the ASP.NET Configuration site that can be found in the "Project" menu in VS2010.

How can I use this in the production server if I don't have VS2010 installed there? Is there any other way to effectively set up this configuration (roles, users...)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you manage asp.net SQL membership roles/users in production?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156563/how-do-you-manage-asp-net-sql-membership-roles-users-in-production)

Comment: 1. is the solution the same for sql server and mysql?

Comment: Yes, it's the same -- the membership provider is driven by configuration.

Comment: 2. check the accepted answer for that question. Does it really answer the question? or is it just a workaround?

Comment: Try the second answer...

Comment: The second answer is not a solution. I don't have VS2010 in my production server. And, regarding the WSAT the person who asks said: "WSAT doesn't help because it needs an initial user in the database before you can do anything, my problem is I have no users in the database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/09/how-to-use-web-site-administration-tool-without-installing-vs-2005.aspx)?

Comment: Hi mifha. Thanks for your response. I had a quick look to the article and it seems a bit outdated. But still, I'm going to try to get it working in that way and keep you posted. Cheers!