# How get users by roles

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
var usersFilterRoles = from u in dataContext.aspnet_Users
join p in dataContext.Partners on u.UserId equals p.Id
where u.aspnet_Roles.Contains(roles)
```

not worked.
roles - I do RoleId or nameRole

I need get users by roles

Answer (score 2):

Get all user names using [Roles.GetUsersInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.getusersinrole.aspx) Method and If you need more information then use [Membership.GetAllUsers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya.aspx) to get all users from the `Membership` and retrieve the Role users from the return `MembershipUserCollection` either using linq or `loop` through MembershipUserCollection and add to custom collection; which method you like best.

```
 MembershipUserCollection users;
  string[] usersInRole;


rolesArray = Roles.GetAllRoles();
users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

Check `GetUsersIndRole` method's link example to clear about the logic.

**Expected Linq Query:**

```
string[] usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Role");
var users = DataContext.AspnetUsers.Where(usr => usersInRole.Contains(usr.LoweredUserName));
```

Follow these tutorials and Links for working with membership.
[ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx)
[How do you manage asp.net SQL membership roles/users in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156563/how-do-you-manage-asp-net-sql-membership-roles-users-in-production)

[Roles.AddUsersToRole Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstorole.aspx)

[Roles Class - Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles_methods.aspx)

Comment: No. I need query from database

Comment: If I need get "User" "Administrator" ? And I need join with Partners

Comment: BTW Mr.@Deniskad Nobody is here to do you job. everyone can give you idea and approach to get your target.  so go to the GetUserInRole documentation at MSDN. There you will get all information .. and about your joining a user to another role etc.. i am updating some links in answer and .. change your approach to be depend on web. here you can get ideas not all your prepared work.

Comment: check these links.. these will let you know about all expects that you are trying to do.   well that was just suggestion.. happy to help..

Answer (score 0):

why not using System.Web.Security.Roles ?

```
using System.Web.Security;

namespace App.SomeName
{
    public class YourClass 
    {
         public void GetUsers(){
               string[] users = Roles.GetUsersInRole("MyRole"); 
         }
    }

}
```

Is this what you wanted to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the ASP.NET Role and Membership provider is the way to go but if you want to get the users by role in linq:

```
var userRoleQuery = from anu in context.AspNetUsers
                               where anu.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Id == roleId)
                               select anu.Id
```